# how do I avoid "not subscriptable" type checks from Pylint when I later set a variable value?

Tags: python, pylint, type-hinting

I have some python code I'm trying to type hint PEP484 style, and getting spurious warnings.

Going through a loop, I first initialize a `last_row` to None.
on the first pass I give it a value, and then next time I do something with it.
However, Pylint still thinks it's `None` even though I declared the type as a `Dict`

How to avoid best this?

I thought of putting some value *other* than `None` on initialize just to shut up the linter, but this seems like a hack.

`last_row: Dict = {}`

Maybe the linter is pointing to a code smell and I should fix this to have a more consistent type/value for the `last_row` ...

```
        last_row: Dict = None

        for index, row in self.df.iterrows():
            if last_row is not None:
                row['intent_from'] = str(last_row['intent'])
            last_row = row
```

in the code above I get this error:

`Value 'last_row' is unsubscriptable`

I believe the typescript checker is smarter about these kind of things, but it is making a runtime guess so that also feels a bit fragile.

Answer (score 3):

One option is to define the type hint as a Union of Dict and None, however, that would have a different problem. It doesn't assure that it's subscriptable.

The problem is that `None` is not of type dictionary, so `last_row: Dict = None` is incorrect.

A solution for this could be initializing the dictionary as an empty dictionary and then checking if the key exists before accessing it.

```
last_row: Dict = {}

for index, row in self.df.iterrows():
    if 'intent' in last_row:
        row['intent_from'] = str(last_row['intent'])
    last_row = row
```

Comment: "Union of [X] and None" is better written as [`Optional[X]`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/typing.html#typing.Optional)

Comment: this is one option... but it seems more like runtime type checking, so it kind of defeats the purpose. it does silence the type checker tho it's true.

Comment: You can also use 'if last_row:' if you only want to check that is not empty

Answer (score 2):

### Answer for python  3.9

As of python 3.9, typing.Dict is deprecated.
The reason for deprecating typing.Dict is that classes now support brackets for type annotation. Now, built in classes are recognized as generics.

from [mypy Documentation](https://mypy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/cheat_sheet_py3.html#built-in-types):

```
# For mappings, we need the types of both keys and values
x: dict[str, float] = {'field': 2.0}  # Python 3.9+
x: Dict[str, float] = {'field': 2.0}
```

With the second example being deprecated from python 3.9

Comment: Bear in mind that [`typing.Dict`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/typing.html#typing.Dict) is deprecated ([PEP 585](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0585/)). If you're answering for an old version of Python, you should probably mention that explicitly.

Answer (score 1):

Python mypy checker supports argument [strict_optional](https://mypy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/config_file.html?highlight=strict_optional#confval-strict_optional) which when set in `mypy.ini` as `strict_optional=False` will treat `Optional[Dict]` as `Dict`. By default it is set to `True`. Also the same function is achievable by passing `--no-strict-optional` as command line flag.

Example:

```
d: dict[str, str] = None
```

Default mypy output

```
error: Incompatible types in assignment (expression has type "None",
variable has type "Dict[str, str]")
    d: dict[str, str] = None
```

With `--no-strict-optional`

Mypy output

```
$mypy --no-strict-optional filename.py
Success: no issues found in 1 source file
```